# How to lock NatTable to left side

Tags: nattable

How would I be able to lock the NatTable on the left side so that it appears as though the data is moving through the columns, rather than the columns moving through the view? This would also solve the problem of having a column be cut-off on the left side.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the question

Comment: When scrolling the NatTable, it visually appears as though the columns are actually moving. What I am trying to do is have the columns visually appear as though they aren't moving, but the data inside them instead changes. So if I were to drag the scrollbar to the right, the data from column 2 would now appear in column 1 without the columns themselves appearing to have shifted to the left.

Comment: So you ask for column based scrolling instead of pixel based scrolling? Is that correct? Actually we spent a lot of effort in moving from column based to smooth scrolling. Not sure how we could bring back the old behavior. You could have a look at the scrollbar handlers and check if you are able to customize them to work like you want. There is no configuration to change that easily.